# Find the word with numbers

Tags: word, number-sequence, word-problem

You are supposed to find a **8-letter word** from the weird clock below by forming one or two digit numbers in an CCS or CS order and take first or last letter of the spelling of that number you have chosen. You can read it clockwise or counterclockwise!
[image]

For example; If the clock below given and asked for 6 letter word, the methodology would be like below:

If we choose going clockwise direction in this clock and starting with 6 and 6,30,44,12,9,2 we get the word STREET: **S**ix**T**hirtyfourtyfou**R**twelv**E**nin**E****T**wo.

[image]

Comment: To anybody solving,make 3 two-digit numbers and 5 single digits , and start from the 0,2,0 it will lead somewhere.

Comment: I don't know whether you're looking for a unique solution, but as a future puzzling tip: always be careful of combinatorial explosions. For example, `ninE, twenty-siX, Three, zerO, forty-fouR, Twelve` for the second example gives `EXTORT` and `Forty, threE, Six, Twenty-nine, twenty-onE, fouR` gives `FESTER`, say.

Comment: @sp3000 it is 8 letter word and there is unique answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is

> forty-one

obtained from

> Four, One, ninety-fouR, Ten, twentY, One, seveN, ninE
>
>  4, 1, 94, 10, 20, 1, 7, 9

Admittedly I ran a search and couldn't find any other 8-letters in the main puzzle.